# Override bootstrap css only in one react component

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

so I'm using a gorgeous search bar component that I found on codepen in my react (CRA) project.
I have imported css in the default src/index.js
Then I have my search component which is composed of Search.js and Search.module.css.

Clearly Bootstrap styling and the Search component styling doesn't work together, when I comment the bootstrap file import in src/index.js, the Search component will be working fine.

So how can I override bootstrap only on my Search Component?
Here is the css of the Search.module.css

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700");

* {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.flexbox {
    background: linear-gradient(155deg, #cccccc, #e8ecee, #d4d4d4);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.search {
    margin: 20px;
}

.search>h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.search>h1,
.search>h3 {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #eaeff1;
}

.search>div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.search>div:after {
    content: "";
    background: white;
    width: 4px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 2px;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    box-shadow: 1px 0 #eaeff1;
}

.search>div>input {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: transparent;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 3px white;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 35px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px #eaeff1;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

.search>div>input::placeholder {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    opacity: 1;
}

.search>div>input::-ms-placeholder {
    color: #efefef;
}

.search>div>input::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #5a5a5a;
}

.search>div>input:focus,
.search>div>input:valid {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: "Clearly Bootstrap styling and the Search component styling doesn't work together" - Why _clearly_? No code has been shown. How can we know what isn't working?

Comment: here is the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't shared the code snippets. I am assuming the bootstrap search will be using: `text` and `button` tag. Now, the CSS of this would be coming from bootstrap.

You can do the following:

1) Make a search component level class eg "search-module"
2) Now, create css or scss file import in the search component and within that css 
override the bootstrap css by :

```
.search-module input[type=search] {...}
```

OR

3) you can do this overriding on your main style.css file too.

You need do to step 2 for all the other conflicting classes, tags, and IDs in the bootstrap with the search component.

PS: This will bloat your CSS. Best would be if you can just pick that part of Bootstrap which is required and rest you write your own style.

Thank you.

Comment: So I have to rename the classes to avoid the styling bugs, Thank you.